# Null pointer on imageview.setBackgroundResource

Tags: android

I have an imageview in a layout called footer.xml which is actually added as footer for the listview.I need to dynamically display images at the end of the listview.So i have referred the imageview in my java file as below

```
    ImageView footerimage;
    View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);//This is the footer layout which i have added to the listview
    footerimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im);
    footerimage.setBackgroundResource(images[i]);//images is an integer array which has drawable resources and i value is not null.
    lv.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception in the fourth line of the above code.I have also changed the images[i] to R.drawable.someimage but the NPE still exist.
Below is my footer Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it should be:

```
footerimage = (ImageView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.im);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer candy...I felt really dumb.